# Pedal assist sensor possible for front wheel motor on ebike?

Tags: electric-bike, modification

I'm looking into converting my current bike into e-bike. I run with IGH, so the only place for the motor is the front wheel.

Is it possible to have pedal assist sensor (PAS) with this setup? I.e. no throttle mode, provides power only when you are pedaling.

If yes - can you provide examples of sensors, controls, etc. which could be used?

I am using Hollowtech II bottom bracket.

Comment: Yes it is possible. https://www.geoo.com/pages/how-it-works

Comment: Why is crank based assist not possible?

Comment: @Paparazzi, I did not know it was an option. But looking into it now - it is ugly as hell :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can have pedelec sensors (PAS) for a front-wheel hub. We're not a shopping site but you just have to go to one of the larger vendors of kits to find one that has a front wheel PAS.

[image: Ebikes.ca list of hubs]

PAS sensors are divided between cheap rotational sensors and more expensive ("advanced") torque sensors. PAS controllers on the whole tend to be more expensive than throttle-only controllers because not only do you need the PAS sensor but the controller has to be more sophisticated in order to balance torque and speed.  All my ebikes have cheap rotational sensors, but if you have the money and your bottom bracket is compatible and you like the challenge, a torque sensor provides for a smoother and more natural assist.

Note that another option is to run a mid-drive (crank based) motor with your IGH. After-market mid-drives would include the Bafang BBS-HD amongst others. However, I'd only do this with a higher-end IGH (Rohloff, higher end Shimano) as the torque from the Bafang + pedaling might be too much for cheaper IGHs. Also note that the Bafang uses a rotational sensor at present but adding a gear-sensor to a mid-drive will make it less likely to strip your IGH gears.

I've deliberately not included links, as you can google yourself.

Comment: P.s. We welcome geeky discussion about the build in [chat].